# Cut column of a file in Linux

Tags: linux

I'm gonna cut a data file in Linux but I'm not familiar with the code of Linux, here is my problem:

I've got a file with format like this:

```
704  11785
9037     1  0   0   000200011101010001202022020002002020001000000
6657     1  0   0   000202011101010002000100001001002220001000000
1831     1  0   0   000002222222020002000122000010200002202022222
```

I want to keep the first 4 columns and the 5th column with only the 10 first numbers like this:

```
704  11785
9037     1  0   0   0002000111
6657     1  0   0   0002020111
1831     1  0   0   0000022222
```

The columns were separated by space, which command should I use to cut my data file? Thanks.

Comment: Linux is an operating system kernel. It doesn't have "data files". You're confusing something there. Where does that file come from? What is contained in there? Why is this specific to Linux at all? To me, that just looks like a text file in which strings of decimals are separated by blank spaces.

Comment: Always add at least an attempt at what you've done to solve the problem, otherwise, it looks like we're doing your job / your homework

Comment: It's my first time to work on a large genetic data which were stored on a computing cluster in a remote platform, that need me to use Linux for manipulating. Here my data file contains the sequencing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@m.antkowicz almost gave you the answer:

```
awk '{printf "%s %s %s %s \n",$1,$2,$3,substr($4,0,10}' filename
```

is the best way I guess. with printf you can set variables and setting up your format for the output (like the \n).

Due to the comment, there is an edit:

```
awk '{printf "%s %s %s %.10s \n",$1,$2,$3,$4}' filename
```

would print the variable $4 (which is the 4th column) to a placeholder for a string with 10 chars (%.10s).
the printf method in awk is equal to the printf in other programming languages. You can specify your output Typ with different placeholder. 
There are:

- %d decimal
- %x hex
- %o octal
- %f float
- %s string
- %c character

So printf can cast a variable to the specific placeholder, e.g.

```
awk '{x=30;printf "%o",x}'
```

would give you the octal value of 36. Due to that you can also have simple calculus like

```
awk '{printf "%d\n",$1+$2}'
```

for adding the first and the second column and print it as decimal value.

But there can also be fault stuff like

```
awk '{x="a";printf "%d",x}'
```

this wouldn't work due to the fact, you're having a charvar x and want to print a decimal.

Comment: it's a placeholder for a string. if you know which type the variable $i has you can have a different placeholder like %f for float or %d for decimal. also you can simple trim the string instead of substr(...) with `%.10s`. It displays the first 10 chars of the string. the result would be `{printf "%s %s %s %.10s \n",$1,$2,$3,$4}`

Comment: is that means I can specify the type of variable for each column after cutting the file?

Comment: you can specify the output type. In which way printf it will handle it. I'll give an update to my answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AWK

```
    awk '{ print $1" "$2" "$3" "substr($4, 0, 10) }' data_file_name
```

Comment: Thanks. I've got this:
`70411785
90371000002000111
66571000002020111
18311000000022222
`
How  could I keep the space between each column?

Comment: also I'm not sure why I got -1 without comment or anything:)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's Ok.

Comment: Glad to help you - If the answer fits your requirements you can accept it - [read more here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)